# Not seeing network messages in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am running a `react`/`node` application on my laptop. When I execute `localhost:3000`, I am getting `404` from `node`. To debug, I want to see the request and response in browser window. However, I don't see anything in `Edge's` network console window. Where can I see outgoing request and incoming response in browser window in `Edge`?

[image]

Comment: On the upper pane, the network inspector is to the right, two tabs over from what you currently have selected. The bottom pane, "Network Console," isn't an inspector, it's for sending requests (similar to a slimmed-down version of Postman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer Tools can be accessed by pressing Ctrl-Shift-I. This is also true for Chrome and Firefox.

Once you have Dev Tools open, select the Network tab at the top of the window.